# Priority Inversion

Tags: operating-system

How many tasks are needed for priority inversion to happen??..As per as my understanding we need atleast 3.....or can we have it only with 2 task??

I actually went through a book : modern operating system by Andrew Tanenbaum . I knew only when 3 task are there in some patern as u all know ..a priority inversion can happen..however ..I found the book says only 2 two task 1-low and the 1-high can also cause the same..so I am confused...

Comment: Could you provide a little more context please.

Comment: I think he means something to do with this; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion

Comment: The problem could occur with two tasks if and only if the execution speed of the task holding the resource could be impaired by its low priority, *even when it is the only unblocked task in the system*.  For example, some processors have low-power modes which can't run at maximum speed, but which consume less energy per instruction.  If the OS were to switch the CPU into such a "low speed/low power" mode while running low-priority tasks (a sensible thing to do, from an energy-conservation standpoint), priority inversion could occur even with only two real tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need one high-priority task which waits for a resource held by a low-priority task, while a mid-priority task is running.

So yes, you need three.

Answer (score 0):

priority inversion can occur with 2 thread also,
Ex:-

Higer priority task waiting on a low priority task which holds a spinlock effectively disabling preemption of the task by higher priority one.